# Is there a way to switch from Fedora without wiping the home partition?

Tags: partitioning, fedora

Is there a way to switching from fedora without wiping home partition?
I download cyanogenmod source code and it took about 3 days to downloading 10 GB no way to backup 10 GB
I can't redownload again but can I switching to ubuntu without remove it

Answer (score 1):

> without wiping home partition

Maybe but I would not advice it. Redhat Fedora and Ubuntu are different though you can share a /home between the 2 if you remove Fedora you will have files on your disc that are useless.

I would do it like this:

- Install gParted, resize disc, make unallocated space and create a new partition in that unallocated space.
- Move the files you need to save to that new partition.
- Install Ubuntu with format and mount the new partition without a format.
- Move files from the back-up partition to you new /home

Tip: separates the root ("/") and your personal file ("/ home"), creating two partition (one for "/ home" and one for "/"). Thus, in case of re-installation, there will be no need to save the file in "/ home" (you'll just have to mount the correct partition in "/ home" without formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The Ubuntu installer allows you to map WITHOUT FORMATTING existing partitions. I am not sure about LVM2 configured volumes, but there is a very good chance that the Ubuntu installer will also recognize such volumes.

Anyway, the trick is to choose the same file system that exists on "use as" installer screen box, using a manual partitioning scheme.

The best choice will be to boot first in rescue mode (Fedora or Ubuntu ), manually mount each partition, and manually move existing data to a nonstandard  directory  (for example, move your `/home` to `/_home`, `/usr`
to `/_usr`)

The only partition that needs to be formatted is swap.
You can safely delete data on `/boot` or format the `/boot` partition if `/boot` is on separate partition

On CentOS/RedHat/Fedora, the current installer has no such option. Instead it is REQUIRED to format the root partition - so if you have `/home` on the root partition you will lose data. If the underlying OS is the same (CentOS vs. CentOS, same version) the partition will be chosen automatically (as far as i know) by the Anaconda installer.